# Linq most efficient way

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing what I need done below:

```
    return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") 
    ? dbContext.Prog_Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper).Where(a => a.Id == 2)      
    : dbContext.Prog_Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper).Where(a => a.Id == 1)
```

I was wondering if there is a clever way of using just one

```
     dbContext.Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper)
```

versus the 2 that I am using and then doing a Where clause conditionally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you want something like:

```
int targetId = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") ? 2 : 1;
return dbContext.Prog_Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper)
                .Where(a => a.Id == targetId);
```

Note that this doesn't really change the *efficiency*, but it does affect the readability.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like this:

```
var id = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") ? 2 : 1
return dbContext.Prog_Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper)
                .Where(a => a.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
var srch = dbContext.Prog_Search1(searchField, searchString, searchOper);
return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") 
    ? srch.Where(a => a.Id == 2)      
    : srch.Where(a => a.Id == 1);
```

Is less tidy in your particular instance than just pre-setting `i=1 or 2`, but more flexible generally should the two different `Where` commands be more different.